# Unable to use synapse.ml.lightgbm in AWS Glue

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, azure-synapse

I am trying to use synapse.ml.lightgbm in AWS Glue. While calling the ltgbm = LightGBMRegressor(labelCol="target", featuresCol=assembler.getOutputCol(),**lgbm_fit_args_final) , I am getting below error:

**Py4JError: com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.lightgbm.LightGBMRegressor does not exist in the JVM**

Code :

```
    Glue Notebook:
    %idle_timeout 2880
    %glue_version 4.0
    %worker_type G.8X
    %number_of_workers 20
    %additional_python_modules synapseml==0.10.2
    %extra_jars "s3://east-1/jars/synapseml-core_2.12-0.10.2.jar,s3://east-1/jars/synapseml-lightgbm_2.12-0.10.2.jar"
    %%configure
    {
        "--conf": "spark.jars.packages=com.microsoft.azure:synapseml_2.12:0.10.2" 
    }
    
    import sys
    from awsglue.transforms import *
    from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
    from awsglue.context import GlueContext
    from awsglue.job import Job
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext, SparkConf
    ltgbm = LightGBMRegressor(labelCol="target", featuresCol=assembler.getOutputCol(),**lgbm_fit_args_final)
```

Output:
Trying to create a Glue session for the kernel.
Session Type: glueetl
Worker Type: G.8X
Number of Workers: 20
Session ID: 13f9e7f3-166222
Applying the following default arguments:
--glue_kernel_version 1.0.4
--enable-glue-datacatalog true
--conf spark.jars.packages=com.microsoft.azure:synapseml_2.12:0.10.2
--extra-jars s3://east-1/jars/synapseml-core_2.12-0.10.2.jar,s3://east-1/jars/synapseml-lightgbm_2.12-0.10.2.jar
--additional-python-modules synapseml==0.10.2
Waiting for session 13f9e7f39e6222 to get into ready status...
Session 13f9e7f3-167f-4cf9-a6a5-8d44dc9e6222 has been created.